# How can i use bash to find 2 values that appear on the same line of a file?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I have 3 files:
File 1:

```
1111111
2222222
3333333
4444444
5555555
```

File 2:

```
6666666
7777777
8888888
9999999
```

File 3

```
8888888 7777777
9999999 6666666
4444444 8888888
```

I want to search file 3 for lines that contain a string from both file 1 and file 2, so the result of this example would be:

```
4444444 8888888
```

because `444444` is in file 1 and `888888` is file 2.

I currently have a solution, however my files contain 500+ lines and it can take a very long time to run my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat file1 | while read line
do
cat file2 | while read line2
do
grep -w -m 1 "$line" file3  | grep -w -m 1 "$line2" >> results
done
done
```

How can i improve this script to run this faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current process is going to be slow due to the repeated scans of `file2` (once for each row in `file1`) and `file3` (once for each row in the cartesian product of `file1` and `file2`).  The additional invocation of sub-processes(as a result of the pipes `|`) is also going to slow things down.

So, to speed this up we want to look at reducing the number of times each file is scanned and limit the number of sub-processes we spawn.

Assumptions:

- there are only 2 fields (when using white space as delimiter) in each row of `file3` (eg, we won't see a row like `"field1 has several strings" "and field2 does, too"`) otherwise we will need to come back revisit the parsing of `file3`

First our data files (I've added a couple extra lines):

```
$ cat file1
1111111
2222222
3333333
4444444
5555555
5555555    # duplicate entry

$ cat file2
6666666
7777777
8888888
9999999

$ cat file3
8888888 7777777
9999999 6666666
4444444 8888888
8888888 4444444      # switch position of values
8888888XX 4444444XX  # larger values; we want to validate that we're matching on exact values and not sub-strings
5555555 7777777      # want to make sure we get a single hit even though 5555555 is duplicated in `file1`
```

One solution using `awk`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN      { filenum=0 }
FNR==1     { filenum++ }
filenum==1 { array1[$1]++ ; next }
filenum==2 { array2[$1]++ ; next }
filenum==3 { if ( array1[$1]+array2[$2] >= 2 || array1[$2]+array2[$1] >= 2) print $0 }
' file1 file2 file3
```

Explanation:

- this single `awk` script will process our 3 files in the order in which they're listed (on the last line)
- in order to aply different logic for each file we need to know which file we're processing; we'll use the variable `filenum` to keep track of which file we're currently processing
- `BEGIN { filenum=0 }` - initialize our `filenum` variable; while the variable should automatically be set to zero the first time it's referenced, it doesn't hurt to be explicit
- `FNR` maintains a running count of the records processed for the **current file**; each time a new file is opened `FNR` is reset to 1
- when `FNR==1` we know we just started processing a new file, so increment our variable `{ filenum++ }`
- as we read values from `file1` and `file2` we're going to use said values as the indexes for the associative arrays `array1[]` and `array2[]`, respectively
- `filenum==1 { array1[$1]++ ; next }` - create entry in our first associative array (`array1[]`)  with the index equal to field1 (from `file1`); value of the array will be a number > 0 (1 === field exists once in file, 2 == field exists twice in file); `next` says to skip the rest of processing and go to the next row in the current file
- `filenum==2 { array2[$1]++ ; next }` - same as previous command except in this case we're saving fields from `file2` in our second associative array (`array2[]`)
- `filenum==3` - optional because if we get this far in this script we have to be on our third file (`file3`); again, doesn't hurt to be explicit (and makes this easier to read/understand)
- `{ if ( ... ) }` - test if the fields from `file3` exist in both `file1` and `file2`
- `array1[$1]+array2[$2] >= 2` - if (`file3`) field1 is in `file1` and field2 is in `file2` then we should find matches in both arrays and the sum of the array element values should be >= 2
- `array1[$2]+array2[$1] >= 2`- same as previous command except we're testing for our 2 fields (`file3`) being in the opposite source files/arrays
- `print $0` - if our test returns true (ie, the current fields from `file3` exist in both `file1` and `file2`) then print the current line (to stdout)

Running this `awk` script against my 3 files generates the following output:

```
4444444 8888888    # same as the desired output listed in the question
8888888 4444444    # verifies we still match if we swap positions; also verifies 
                   # we're matching on actual values and not a sub-string (ie, no
                   # sign of the row `8888888XX 4444444XX`)
5555555 7777777    # only shows up in output once even though 5555555 shows up
                   # twice in `file1`
```

At this point we've a) limited ourselves to a single scan of each file and b) eliminated all sub-process calls, so this should run rather quickly.

**NOTE**: One trade-off of this `awk` solution is the requirement for memory to store the contents of `file1` and `file2` in the arrays; which shouldn't be an issue for the relatively small data sets referenced in the question.

Comment: Works perfectly and almost instant, this will knock hours off my daily scripts. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it faster if load all data first and than process it

```
f1=$(cat file1)
f2=$(cat file2)

IFSOLD=$IFS; IFS=$'\n'
f3=( $(cat file3) )
IFS=$IFSOLD

for item in "${f3[@]}"; {
    sub=( $item )
    test1=${sub[0]}; test1=${f1//[!$test1]/}
    test2=${sub[1]}; test2=${f2//[!$test2]/}
    [[ "$test1 $test2" == "$item" ]] && result+="$item\n"
}

echo -e "$result" > result
```

Comment: `f1=$(cat file1)`⇒ `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a f1 <file1` and same for `file2` and `file3`.  `sub=( $item )` ⇒ `IFS=' ' read -r test1 test2 <<<"$item"` or `set -- $item; test1="$1"; test2="$2"` then use `$1` and `$2` directly.
Rather than `echo "$item" >> result` move the redirection the the end of the loop `for item in "${f3[@]}"; {...} > result`.